# Identify value of blown capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I need to repair one board of Plasma TV which has a faulty ceramic capacitor, but I'm not sure whats its value.

[image]

Is there any way to identify the value of the blown capacitor ?

Please advise

Thanks
Sam

Comment: likely the same as the other three. to be sure, look into the schematic/bom of the service manual

Answer (score 3):

Remove all and replace with "lowest" ESR ceramic caps of same value from Murata or TDK at Digikey or equiv.  Tolerance is not as important as having them matched from same batch when low ESR is concerned. The highest ESR cap may burn up if ripple current^2*ESR exceeds 100mW

Comment: thanks for your kind suggestion. you mean all 4 c2415 to c2618? what value you suggest to replace with?

Comment: can you not measure the good ones and choose the same value and size in a low ESR brand?  yes all 4 shud be matched otherwise the lowest ESR cap will draw the most ripple current. this is critical for high ripple current sharing to use equally low ESR. Why do think it blew?

Answer (score 2):

There's a moderate chance it will fire up if you simply remove the shorted cap. If so, measure the voltage across the caps. If not, perhaps something else has been fried.

Remove one of the good caps and measure the value. Replace the good one on the board and procure a capacitor of similar capacitance and of significantly higher voltage rating than the measured voltage. For example, if you measure 1uF and 30V, get a 1uF/50V cap.